# Hiding a text box in a form using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

What is the correct way to hide an input text box? The following appears to work in all browsers except *Internet Explorer*. I am testing on IE8.

```
var field = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
field.type = 'hidden';
```

For the record the following does not work:

```
var field = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
field.style.display = 'none';
```

Neither does this work:

```
var field = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
field.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
```

Comment: `does not work` is not a very precise problem description. Are you getting an error message, does your computer crash, do apples start to fall from the sky, ...? Also a complete code snippet containing the HTML and demonstrating the problem would be nice.

Comment: confirm if field is not null and for IE add an alert - alert(field.outerHTML) to confirm if you are pointing to the correct element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The indication when researching this is that IE does not let you do this.

This article explains what you shoudl do to achieve a similar effect:

http://www.universalwebservices.net/web-programming-resources/javascript/change-input-element-type-using-javascript

> However, most of us find it necessary
>   to submit to the demands of Internet
>   Explorer.  To meet these demands, we
>   must:
>
> - dynamically create a new element
> - copy the properties of the old element into the new element
> - set the type of the new element to the new type
> - then replace the old element with the new element

The code is also reproduced by this site, so thought I'd let you visit it for the benefit of page hits for them.

I would be interested as to what is different about IE from the other browsers that causes issues with this.

Also, anyone care to try it on IE9?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why `style.display='none'` doesn't work. Have you tried   `style.visibility = 'hidden'` ?